# Creating separate admin account

Tags: c#, authentication, passwords, admin, account

I am using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express (C#) I am busy creating a website for a project, which involves users registering and logging on to a site. I have done that part, but I am not sure how I can create a separate account for only 1 admin.

I created a new webform and added a new login control, but the new login control only works for registered users, not admin (this maybe due to membership class). How can I create a separate account for one admin?

Comment: Look at "Roles" in ASP.NET

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. One thing is when a user clicks a Navigation Button called "Admin" page, it goes back to the standard login (control) screen. How can I navigate it to another page with an error message, if a non-admin user clicks this Navigation Button? Only found one "NavigateUrl" property for this button, which directs to admin page